# Properly structuring Python packages?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, project, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a Python3.7 package structured like so.

```
project             # Repository
--\README
--\LICENSE
--\setup.py
--\project          # Source
----\project.py
----\__init__.py    # Init1
----\functions
-------\__init__.py # Init2
-------\moduleA.py
-------\ ...
-------\moduleZ.py
```

Inside `project.py` I have the following.

```
from functions.moduleA import functionA
from functions.moduleB import functionB
...
functionA = functionA
functionB = functionB
```

Init2 is completely blank. But Init1 has the following.

```
from .project import functionA
from .project import functionB
```

But when I execute `$ python -c 'import project'` inside the Repository directory, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'`. There is something perhaps very simple that is going wrong here. The import works correctly inside the Source directory though. Ultimately, I'm interested in users installing everything via `setup.py` and using my project like so.

```
import project

project.functionA(...)
...
project.functionB(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `project.py` file doesn't work as you intend. These lines are causing the error:

```
from functions.moduleA import functionA
from functions.moduleB import functionB
```

Those imports don't work because `functions` is not a top-level module, but rather a subpackage that is part of the `project` package. You can fix them by adding a `.` at the start of each module name (`.functions.moduleA`, etc.). I suppose you could also name the absolute module name, if you preferred it for some reason (e.g. `project.functions.moduleA`).

The assignment statements also don't do anything. `functionA = functionA` could be deleted and there would be no difference at all.

It's not really clear to me what the purpose of the `project.py` file is. It seems entirely redundant next to the `project/__init__.py` file, which seems like it's supposed to contain exactly the same values. Probably you should merge them together, into a single file (probably the `__init__.py` file).

I'd also think carefully about whether you really need so many subpackages and modules. While it's sometimes just a matter of style, keeping things that are closely related in the same module can be very handy. You certainly do not need a separate module for every function you write!

Comment: Well I made the changes like you suggested, but when executing `python project.py` from within Source I get the following: `from .functions.moduleA import functionA` throws `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Trying `from project.functions.moduleA import functionA` throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.functions'; 'project' is not a package`. The reason project.py exists is because it is intended to be a cli for the library. Import seems to be working though.

Comment: Running a module in a package as a script is somewhat fraught. You should either use `python -m package.scriptmodule` (though how you get an IDE to do this, I have no idea), or you need the script file to set up a `__package__` global (see [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for details). The filename `__main__.py` is available for containing code that will run if a package is run as a script. You might consider using that instead of the equivalent of `package.package`.